# javascript object not defined whether it worked years ago

Tags: javascript, object

Very little problem, please help!

Javascript object not defined whether it worked years ago:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var obj_Car = new object();
  obj_Car.color = "beige"
  document.write(obj_Car.color);
</script>
```

Comment: Is this old code that used to work or is it code you remember?

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `Object` with a capital `o` - but better - use a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mistake in Object name. JavaScript is case sensitive.

```
var obj_Car = new Object(); // use Object() rather than object()
    obj_Car.color = "beige";
    console.log(obj_Car.color);
```

This may work perfectly.